# Why is GoogleMock leaking my shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, googletest, googlemock

I use GoogleMock/GoogleTest for testing, and I'm seeing some strange behavior when a matcher has a shared_ptr to a mock as a parameter, and EXPECT is called on the same shared_ptr. The offending piece of code:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
using namespace boost;
using namespace testing;

struct MyParameter
{
    virtual ~MyParameter() {}
    virtual void myMethod() = 0;
};

struct MyParameterMock : public MyParameter
{
    MOCK_METHOD0(myMethod, void());
};

struct MyClass
{
    virtual ~MyClass() {}
    virtual void myMethod(shared_ptr<MyParameter> p) {}
};

struct MyClassMock : public MyClass
{
    MOCK_METHOD1(myMethod, void(shared_ptr<MyParameter>));
};

TEST(LeakTest, GoogleMockLeaksMatchedPointer)
{
    shared_ptr<MyClassMock> c = make_shared<MyClassMock>();
    shared_ptr<MyParameterMock> p = make_shared<MyParameterMock>();
    {
        InSequence dummy;
        EXPECT_CALL(*c, myMethod(Eq(p)));
        EXPECT_CALL(*p, myMethod());
    }
    c->myMethod(p);
    p->myMethod();
}
```

When this test is run, I get

```
leak_ptr_mock.cpp:37: ERROR: this mock object (used in test LeakTest.GoogleMockLeaksMatchedPointer) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x9309544.
ERROR: 1 leaked mock object found at program exit.
```

Any idea of why this happens? I rather not have to use `Mock::AllowLeak`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a result of holding `p` as a `shared_ptr`, using `InSequence` and the order in which you have declared your expectations.

When you call

```
    EXPECT_CALL(*c, myMethod(Eq(p)));
```

you increase the `use_count` of `p`.  In order for the leak detection to pass, `p` must be destroyed at (or before) the end of `TEST`.

The problem here is that internally, gmock maintains a record of the required mock call sequence by holding a pointer to the preceding expectation.  So when you call `EXPECT_CALL(*p, myMethod());`, it gets a copy of the pointer to the previous expectation.

This then has the effect of blocking the call to `p`'s destructor when `TEST` ends.

In order to work around this, I think your best bet is to call

```
    EXPECT_TRUE(Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(p.get()));
```

just before you exit `TEST`.  This clears the expectations on `p`, including critically its prerequisite expectation, which in turn allows the destructor of `p` to be invoked correctly.

Alternatively, if the order of the mock calls is unimportant, simply removing `InSequence dummy;` will also allow `p`'s destructor to execute.

As an aside, your code has a couple of issues;

- Your base structs should have virtual destructors
- `MyClass::myMethod` should be virtual in order to allow gmock's function to override it
- `p->myMethod(p);` should be `p->myMethod();`

Comment: It works, Fraser! I corrected the code as per your suggestions too.

Comment: @bruno nery: Which version of GoogleMock are you using?

Comment: What would happen if p is created before c? Wouldn't than at the end c be destroyed, its expectations verified and cleared which will lead in  decrementing the reference counter of p. After that p will be destroyed, verified and completely destroyed since the counter is now 0.

Comment: @Martin No, the order of construction doesn't affect the order of checks since `InSequence dummy;` is used.  Swapping the order of the `EXPECT_CALL`s would allow the test to exit successfully without leaks, but if the order of the expectations doesn't matter, you're as well not using `InSequence` at all.  BTW, I'm using gmock 1.6.0.

Comment: What happens if `p` is a struct?

Comment: What can I do if my shared_pointer is not an explicitly specified one, but an implicitly specified one? Eg. using the _.