# Using googlemock EXPECT_CALL with shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, googlemock

I have a test that works fine with a raw pointer, but I'm having trouble getting it work with a `std::shared_ptr`.  The class is like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass(SomeService *service);
    void DoIt();
}
```

My test code is like:

```
    class MyClassTests : public ::testing::Test
    {
    public:
        MyClassTests():
            myClass_(new MyClass(&service_))
        {}

    protected:
        SomeServiceFake service_;
        MyClassSharedPointer myClass_;
    };

TEST_F(MyClassTests, DoIt_DoesNotMeetCriteria_DoesNotPerformAction) {

    // Arrange
    EXPECT_CALL(service_, MeetsCriteria(_))
        .WillRepeatedly(Return(false));

    EXPECT_CALL(service_, PerformAction(_))
        .Times(0);

    // Act
    myClass_->DoIt();
}
```

In this test, `service_` is a mock/fake created on the stack in the test and I pass the address into the constructor of `MyClass`.  Changing `MyClass` to take `service` as a `shared_ptr`, my new class looks like:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass(std::shared_ptr<SomeService> service);
    DoIt();
}
```

What I'm trying in my test is:

```
    class MyClassTests : public ::testing::Test
    {
    public:
        MyClassTests():
            myClass_(new MyClass(std::shared_ptr<SomeService>(&service_)))
        {

        }
            ...
```

When I do this, however, the test fails with a:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: _CtrlIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)
```

In a nutshell, I need a `shared_ptr` to `service_` (which is a fake object) to pass to the `MyClass` constructor and I need a non-pointer for the `EXPECT_CALL` function. How can I get this to work correctly?

**UPDATE**

Tried dynamically allocating SomeServiceFake to get the shared_ptr and then using the * operator on `service_`, this gets me "further" but now I get the following error:

```
error : this mock object
(used in test MyClassTests.DoIt_DoesNotMeetCriteria_DoesNotPerformAction)
should be deleted but never is. Its address is @009BBA68.
1>EXEC : error : 1 leaked mock object found at program exit.
```

**UPDATE 2**

Using `Mock::AllowLeak(service_.get());` so I can get around this problem for now.  Hopefully I'll get an answer.

Answer (score 10):

Define your test class more like this:

```
class MyClassTests : public ::testing::Test {
 public:
  MyClassTests():
      service_(new SomeServiceFake), myClass_(new MyClass(service_)) {}
 protected:
  std::shared_ptr<SomeServiceFake> service_;
  std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myClass_;
};
```

and your test:

```
  EXPECT_CALL(*service_, MeetsCriteria(_))
      .WillRepeatedly(Return(false));

  EXPECT_CALL(*service_, PerformAction(_))
      .Times(0);
```

Comment: This is an unfortunate shortcoming of gmock - it really doesn't play nice with smart pointers.  I guess your actual code is somewhat more complex than what you've posted here?  There are a few ways in which gmock can give a false positive about a leaked object managed by a smart pointer (e.g. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286514)).  Without the actual code it's difficult to say why gmock reports the leak.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the test framework.  As you said yourself, you are creating a shared_ptr from a stack-allocated object (i.e. one with automatic lifetime).  This does not make sense.  Shared pointers are typically created from the result of `new`.  You might be able to make it work if you pass a custom Deleter as the second argument to the shared_ptr constructor, but best might be to just create the object using new.

Comment: Which makes perfect sense, but if I `new` `SomeServiceFake`, I believe googlemock expects class objects for the `EXPECT_CALL`, how do I achieve that?

Comment: User: Maybe say *service_ to get the reference and pass that to EXPECT_CALL?  @VJovic: I don't understand your comment.