# How to use a (smart) pointer to mocked object (in google mock)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

When I store my mock object on the heap using a `shared_ptr`, the expectations are satisfied and the pointer is destroyed but GMock framework thinks the mock object is still alive:

```cpp
// Using a mock object
MockFoo foo;
EXPECT_CALL(foo, doSomething());
foo.doSomething();
// Test passes without warnings
```

```cpp
// Using shared_ptr to a mock object
auto foo_sp = std::make_shared<MockFoo>();
EXPECT_CALL(*foo_sp, doSomething());
A a(std::move(foo_sp));
a.useFoo();
// a is then deleted
...
// in useFoo:
foo_sp->doSomething();
...
// Test passes WITH warnings that mock object is still alive
```

Is this a bug in the Google mock framework? If not then how can I store my mock object on the heap in a smart pointer and use it correctly?

Comment: What are `foo` and `mock` in your second example?

Comment: I think problem is somewhere deeper. Simple empty class MockFoo doesn't give any warnings for me...

Comment: Is it related to this: [Why is GoogleMock leaking my shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286514/why-is-googlemock-leaking-my-shared-ptr) ?

Comment: Thank you all for pointing me to the right direction. You are right @sklott this was an issue with the owner of the mock object not being destroyed (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @YSC, @sklott and @Yksisarvinen that pointed me to the right direction.

For anyone having a similar issue. It turned out that in my case the issue was unrelated to the Google C++ mocking framework. I was passing the mock object to a derived class, whose base class's destructor was not declared as virtual. Therefore the destructor of the mock owner was never called and the mock object was kept alive.